# Using an iterator to sort a vector by comparison

Tags: c++, vector

I've created a vector of a class called albums and as I add a new album to the vector i'm first trying to compare the album title to the first index of the vector and sort it in alphabetical order. Here is my code:

```
vector<album> cd;                //declared in main

void add_cd_vector(vector<album>& cd)
{
    string name;
    int barcode;


    cout << "Enter the album name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter the barcode: ";
    cin >> barcode;
    album newCD(name, barcode);       //constructor function for class

    if(cd.size() == 0) //no vector created yet
    {
         cd.push_back(newcd);
    }
    else{
         vector<album>::iterator it;
         for(it = cd.begin(); it!=cd.end(); it++)
         {
              if(name < it.get_name())    //getter function for name in  class
              {
                    cd.insert(it, newCD);     //should insert into the vector
              }
          }
    }
```

My problem lies either within my if statement or the command inside of it, i'm not sure the proper syntax.

Comment: What happens when the second element you want to insert is greater than the first?

Comment: are you saying I should add an else statement after the if to push_back():?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to change your insert logic to this:

```
for(it = cd.begin(); it!=cd.end(); it++)
{
    if (name < it->get_name())
    {
        break;
    }
}
cd.insert(it, newCD);
```

This way, the element gets inserted even if it's greater than the last element.  Note that with this logic you need not check if the vector is empty so the code is simpler.

Comment: vector<album>::iterator has no member named get_name is what I get from that